# validation is always true in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Im new to cakePHP and tried to create a simple user registration. Now I'm stuck since two days  in the validation of the form. The validation function returns always true and so the form is always saved to the database, even if it is empty.

So here are the model, the controller and the view. Maybe you can see what I did wrong here?

/app/Model/MemberModel.php

```
<?php
class Member extends AppModel {
    var $validate = array(
        "username" => array(
            "rule" => "alphaNumeric",
            "allowEmpty" => false
        )
    );
}
?>
```

/app/Controller/MemberController.php

```
<?php
class MemberController extends AppController {

    var $components = array("Security");
    var $helpers = array("Html", "Form");

    public function index() {
    }

    public function register() {

        if($this->request->is("post")) {
            Security::setHash("blowfish");
            $this->Member->set($this->request->data);

            debug($this->Member->validates());

            if($this->Member->save(array("password" => Security::hash($this->request->data["Member"]["password"])))) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__("Saved."));


    } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__("Error: ").$this->validationErrors);
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

/app/View/Member/register.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create("Member");
echo $this->Form->input("username");
echo $this->Form->input("password");
echo $this->Form->end("Register");
?>
```

Comment: Can you try outputting the value of username from the request and see what shows up?

Comment: With `debug($this->request->data)` everything seems fine, the username and also the password were successfully submitted and displayed: `array('Member' => array('password' => '*****','username' => 'test'))`

Comment: Right but do you mean `'username' => ''` appears when entering nothing in the username?

Comment: Yes, if I left the field empty this is exactly what debug returns. And thats the point where normally the validation rule should say anything because of 'allowEmpty'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I just realized your problem.

```
/app/Model/MemberModel.php
```

should be

```
/app/Model/Member.php
```

The controller will look for `Member.php`, and if it can't find it, it will try the default `$validate` behavior in `AppModel`